# C# - escaping semicolon and double quotes

Tags: c#, .net

How do you replace ; with ";"? I have tried a few methods from SO:

```
input: sometext,sometext
desired output: sometext","sometext

string s = "sometext,sometext".Replace(',' , "\";\"")
--Error: cannot convert from string to char

string s = "sometext,sometext".Replace(',' , '\";\"')
--Error: Too many characters in character literal

string s = "sometext,sometext".Replace(';', @""";""")
--Error: cannot convert from string to char
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
string s = "sometext,sometext".Replace("," , "\";\"");
```

Both need to be char or string.

Answer (score 1):

Use double quotes:

```
string s = "sometext,sometext".Replace(",", "\";\"");
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two overloaded methods for string.Replace. One which accepts both the arguments as char and another one with strings. You are mixing up the two, and there is no method that matches with this argument type and that is the reason for this error.

You can use the below code for replacing the , with ";"

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string original = "some text, some other text";

            string processed = original.Replace(",", "\";\"");

            Console.WriteLine(processed);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So close, still too late, anyways, per the previous answers you need to replace the single quotes with double quotes, that way you invoke the correct overload, and then something like this

```
string s = "sometext,sometext".Replace(",", "\"" + ";" + "\"");
```